# Function does not give value of variables

Tags: php

The following function gives me the next error afterwards when I tried to echo `$oplossing` after the function:

> Undefined variable: oplossing

I've tried multiple things but somehow it does not take the valua of the variables from inside the function to the rest of the php document. I'm quite new to programming so this might be obvious but I don't know how to do this. How do I fix this?

```
 $moeilijkheidsgraad = $_POST["moeilijkheidsgraad"];
$waarde = $_POST["waarde"];

function WaardeGetal ($moeilijkheidsgraad, $waarde)
{
if ( $moeilijkheidsgraad == "makkelijk" ){      //makkelijk
    if ( $waarde == "dechex" ){                 //van decimaal naar hexadecimaal
        $getal = rand(0,32);                    //willekeurig getal tussen 0 en 50
        $oplossing = dechex($getal);
        $oplossing = strtoupper($oplossing);    //omzetten van decimale getal naar hexadecimaal getal
    }                           


    elseif ( $waarde == "hexdec") {             //hexadecimaal naar decimaal
        $oplossing = rand(0,32);                //willekeurig getal tussen 0 en 50
        $getal = dechex($oplossing);
        $getal = strtoupper($getal);            //omzetten van decimale getal naar hexadecimaal getal
    }

    elseif ($waarde == "decbin") {
        $getal = rand(0,16);
        $oplossing = decbin($getal);
    }

    elseif ($waarde == "hexbin"){
        $getal = rand(0,16);
        $getal = dechex($getal);
        $oplossing = base_convert($getal,16,2);
        $getal = strtoupper($getal);
        }

    elseif ($waarde == "binhex" ) {
        $oplossing = rand(0,16);
        $oplossing = dechex($oplossing);
        $getal = base_convert($oplossing,16,2);
        $oplossing = strtoupper($oplossing);
        $aantal = 0;
        }

    else {
        $oplossing = rand(0,16);
        $getal = decbin($oplossing);
    }
    }

else {                                          //moeilijk
    if ( $waarde == "dechex" ){                 //van decimaal naar hexadecimaal
        $getal = rand(32,256);                  //willekeurig getal tussen 0 en 50
        $oplossing = dechex($getal);            //omzetten van decimale getal naar hexadecimaal getal
        $oplossing = strtoupper($oplossing);
        }

  elseif  ( $waarde =="hexdec" ){               //hexadecimaal naar decimaal
        $oplossing = rand(32,256);              //willekeurig getal tussen 0 en 50
        $getal = dechex($oplossing);            //omzetten van decimale getal naar hexadecimaal getal
        $getal = strtoupper($getal);    
    }

    elseif ($waarde == "decbin") {
        $getal = rand(16,256);
        $oplossing = decbin($getal);
    }

    elseif ($waarde == "hexbin"){
        $getal = rand(16,256);
        $getal = dechex($getal);
        $oplossing = base_convert($getal,16,2);
        $getal = strtoupper($getal);
        }

    elseif ($waarde == "binhex" ) {
        $oplossing = rand(16,256);
        $oplossing = dechex($oplossing);
        $getal = base_convert($oplossing,16,2);
        $oplossing = strtoupper($oplossing);
        }

    else {
        $oplossing = rand(16,256);
        $getal = decbin(oplossing);
    }
 }
 return
 }

WaardeGetal($moeilijkheidsgraad, $waarde);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare both `$waarde` and `$oplossing` before your function and then call `global $waarde, $oplossing` inside your function.

This occured as the varibles inside your function had a local scope and not a global one

Comment: It fixed the errors I had, but how do I take the new values of $oplossing and $getal outside the function again?

Comment: You should be fine to just call them as you normally would after the function. Any variables you want to access outside the function you should declare outside and then make it global inside.

Comment: just return them : return ['oplossing' => $oplossing, 'getal' => $getal];